# C++ Common Language Runtime Support [.Net?]

Tags: c++, c++-cli, clr

**Hi guys!**
This is not a big issue, however, I was wondering whether when you enable the option "Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)" it requires the ".net framework" or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enabling CLR support in a C++ project will indeed add a dependency on the .Net framework.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! =] I unfourtaintly can not give you any reputation, due to the low amount of reputation I got [9]. Anyways, thank you!